# How to call phone in android fragment class?

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to call to phone when I click OK button. Now I am getting error

Error message

```
12-23 17:19:39.547: E/AndroidRuntime(4095): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=91 90-37-300100 flg=0x10000000 }
```

Here is my code

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {
private View parentView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, container, false);
    parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, container, false);
    setUpViews();
    return parentView;
}   

 private void setUpViews() {
     parentView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Creating alert Dialog with two Buttons
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Do you want to call?");
            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("+91 XXXXXXXXXX");
            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.warning);
            // Setting Negative "NO" Button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("91 XXXXXXXXXX"));
                            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(callIntent);

                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
 }  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("91 XXXXXXXXXX"));
```

with this:

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "91XXXXXXXXXX"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("91 XXXXXXXXXX"));
```

with

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "91 XXXXXXXXXX"));
```

Just add **"tel:"** before adding your number.

So basically you have to call like below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

just replace your code with:

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "91XXXXXXXXXX"));
 getActivity().startActivity(callIntent);
```

and Add permission for call in **manifest** file

Comment: This is the correct answer. You cannot use  startActivity(callIntent); directly from a Fragment. You have to first retrieve the activity using getActivity and then startActivity(callIntent) as given here.